# File Writing using PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a project in my college which is about developing an online autograder website like that of hackerrank for my college. Now, for compiling codes, I am using the API provided by sphere engines. The API is returning the output as a string which then I store it into a file. Then, I use a previously defined output file to compare this file and check accordingly  whether the code is right or wrong. Now the problem is for eg. if output is like below:

Hello World

Hello World

Hello World

The string is written in the file as Hello WorldHello WorldHwllo World. I am using PHP to write text to file.

Is there any way to write the string as it is to a file?
Any other alternative method will also be appreciated.

Thank You.

EDIT

for eg if the code:

```
#include<iotsream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
 cout<<"Hello World\n";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

The output of this code should be

Hello World

Hello World

Hello World

And when i am displaying the string which is stored in a PHP array $data['output'], it is getting displayed normally but when i am writing this string to a file, It is getting stored in a single line. I want to store the string as it is i.e. in different lines.

Due to this, this file if not equal to the template output file which contains the string Hello World in different lines.

EDIT
This is the PHP code for the file which will take the source code and input and send it to the compiler and receive it's output accordingly.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once '../connection-script.php';
session_start();


$user = 'xxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxx';
$code = '';
$input = '';
$run = true;
$private = false;

$subStatus = array(
    0 => 'Success',
    1 => 'Compiled',
    3 => 'Running',
    11 => 'Compilation Error',
    12 => 'Runtime Error',
    13 => 'Timelimit exceeded',
    15 => 'Success',
    17 => 'memory limit exceeded',
    19 => 'illegal system call',
    20 => 'internal error'
);

$error = array(
    'status' => 'error',
    'output' => 'Something went wrong :('
);

//echo json_encode( array( 'hi', 1 ) ); exit;
//print_r( $_POST ); exit;

if ( isset( $_POST['process'] ) && $_POST['process'] == 1 ) {
    $lang = isset( $_POST['lang'] ) ? intval( $_POST['lang'] ) : 1;
    $input = trim( $_POST['input'] );
    $code = trim( $_POST['source'] );
    $answerfile=$_POST['answerfile'];
    $outputfile=$_POST['outputfile'];

    $client = new SoapClient( "http://ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl" );

    //create new submission
    $result = $client->createSubmission( $user, $pass, $code, $lang, $input, $run, $private );

    //if submission is OK, get the status
    if ( $result['error'] == 'OK' ) {
        $status = $client->getSubmissionStatus( $user, $pass, $result['link'] );
        if ( $status['error'] == 'OK' ) {

            //check if the status is 0, otherwise getSubmissionStatus again
            while ( $status['status'] != 0 ) {
                sleep( 3 ); //sleep 3 seconds
                $status = $client->getSubmissionStatus( $user, $pass, $result['link'] );
            }

            //finally get the submission results
            $details = $client->getSubmissionDetails( $user, $pass, $result['link'], true, true, true, true, true );
            if ( $details['error'] == 'OK' ) {
                //print_r( $details );
                if ( $details['status'] < 0 ) {
                    $status = 'waiting for compilation';
                } else {
                    $status = $subStatus[$details['status']];
                }

                $data = array(
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'meta' => "Status: $status | Memory: {$details['memory']} | Returned value: {$details['status']} | Time: {$details['time']}s",
                    'output' => htmlspecialchars( $details['output'] ),
                    'raw' => $details
                );


                if( $details['cmpinfo'] ) {
                    $data['cmpinfo'] = $details['cmpinfo'];
                }

                $myfile=fopen("output.txt","w");
                fwrite($myfile, $data['output']); 
                fclose($myfile);

                $qid=$_POST['questionid'];
                $did=$_POST['domainid'];

                if(sha1_file("output.txt") == sha1_file($outputfile))
                {

                $file=fopen($answerfile,"w");
                fwrite($file,$code);
                fclose($file);

                $mail=$_SESSION['email'];
                $query="SELECT * from student where semail='$mail'";
                $result1=mysql_query($query);
                $row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
                $sid=$row1['studentid'];


                $sql="SELECT * from practiceques where did='$did' and quesid='$qid'";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $marks=$row['marks'];

                $curdate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                $answer=mysql_query("INSERT INTO points VALUES ('$sid','$qid','$curdate',1,'$marks','$did')");

                echo json_encode( $data );

                }
                else 
                {
                    $mail=$_SESSION['email'];
                    $query="SELECT * from student where semail='$mail'";
                    $result1=mysql_query($query);
                    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
                    $sid=$row1['studentid'];



                    $sql="SELECT * from practiceques where did='$did' and quesid='$qid'";
                    $result=mysql_query($sql);
                    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    $marks=$row['marks'];

                    $curdate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                    $answer=mysql_query("INSERT INTO points VALUES ('$sid','$qid','$curdate',0,0,'$did')");
                    echo json_encode($data);
                }
            } 
            else {
                //we got some error :(
                //print_r( $details );
                echo json_encode( $error );
            }
        } 
        else {
            //we got some error :(
            //print_r( $status );
            echo json_encode( $error );
        }
    } else {
        //we got some error :(
        //print_r( $result );
        echo json_encode( $error );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Give an example of code that you have now, and which does not give the desired result.

Comment: Update your question by real code example.

Comment: This sounds like you should read a bit about different line encodings in different operating systems. It could be that that API you use returns normal unix / internet linebreaks, whilst you are used to / expect MS-Windows like linebreaks.

Comment: wrong code. this is not real code

Comment: which code are you asking about? the API code?

Comment: What code? Seriously?  You only put 1 block of code in the question and it certainly isnt the PHP code you refer to.

Comment: Sir, read the question again. I have written it there that i am making a website like hackerrank for my college. Now, a user enters a code, let it be any language,  an online compiler API provided by sphere engines takes the source code, it's input from an HTML form. The code for sending the source code and receiving output and all it's meta data from the API is written in PHP.

Comment: If you want to write the file exactly as is, just remove the htmlspecialchars call. Perhaps you want it because you are writing a html file.  You should use the extension .html rather than .txt.  Also try using the nl2br function on the data before you write it.

Comment: Also test what happens if you change your source code to `cout<<"Hello World\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

You can't write with C in php document.
Anyway, This is the php code for write in file.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('file.name', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, 'Hello World'.PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Sir, I didnt think you understood my problem. I am making a project to make a website like hackerrank for my college. I am using an online compiler API provided by sphere engines to compile the code entered by the user. The online compiler takes the language preference, source code and input using an HTML form and then returns the source code output, it's running time etc. It returns it output in a form of a string,